# Change input language for selected Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a text area in my application. I want to programmatically set the input language for the text area alone without affecting other controls.

Comment: Sorry, asp.net text area. Or even textbox. Whatever input control it may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this can't be done by your program. The user needs to use Unicode keyboard or Input method Editor (IME). Since you're using C#/.Net platform, your program is already capable of dealing with unicode inputs. You just read the value from textbox as

```
string str = Textbox1.Text
```

str will contain the unicode input given by the User.

`Ex:` Look at the text below, I have written the word MICROSOFT in indic language using my Indic-IME. You may notice that there's nothing additionally done on this website to display this text below. It's just my indic language IME.

माइक्रोसॉफ्ट

Some sample unicode IMEs for indian language can be found [here](http://bhashaindia.com/Downloads/Pages/home.aspx)..

Comment: Sorry. I dont get your explanation. Consider i want to have the chinese language for that textbox. So if i type the text in that box i want to appear it in Chinese. How to do that?

Comment: You cannot do that. The end user will need to use Chinese IME to provide input to your textbox. .Net framework already gives you a textbox that can take any unicode compatible language input.