# How to fix English language to specific textbox in Arabic Input language mode?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to fix the English language as input language even if the user selects Arabic keyboard for particular textbox.

Is it possible?

Once I set the input languae as English, it's changing to all textboxes and labels. But I am looking to fix it to English language for a particular textbox only.

Comment: Winforms and Thanks For Enquiries

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible using the following in the Windows application.

```
    private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo TypeOfLanguage = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us");
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(TypeOfLanguage);
    }
```

Comment: No. Above will change to all textboxes..I don't want it. I need to fix only to one textbox not for all.

Comment: so you can change it back   to default language in Leave event

Comment: But while textbox_enters labels languages will change...I need only for particular textbox not for all..thanks

Comment: many years ago when os doesnt support Farsi or arabic we were handling it by managing userkeypress and mapping it to Arabic like a when user press A we were replacing it with ش in arabic ... it doesnt need to change input language also many Persian or arabic web site doing same with verysmall javascript function

Answer (score 1):

```
  this.textBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBox1_KeyDown);
```

You can add `KeyEventHandler` for your textbox, if you are using the WinForms, and analize the `KeyDown` event, something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571297/keypress-event-for-winforms-textbox-is-missing)

Answer (score 1):

It defaults to English language I believe, and I don't think there is any "language" property present for textbox ... provided it's a web form. Take a look at Stack Overflow post *[Change input language for selected Controls - ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934249/change-input-language-for-selected-controls-asp-net)*.

Answer (score 0):

If this is WebForms you may well be able to use the solution in this question: [Arabic text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008390/arabic-text-box/4323306#4323306)

Something like (using [jQuery](http://jquery.com)):

```
$("#textBox").attr("lang", "en");
```

Comment: Could whoever downvoted this comment on why? If something needs fixing, let the person know.  Chances are, after over 7 years, things might have changed.